# Importing Whisper in Azure Databricks gives an import error for Numba, despite installing the right version of NumPy

Tags: numpy, nlp, databricks, numba, openai-whisper

I want to implement Whisper in Azure Databricks for a transcription task. Installing Whisper works fine. When importing the module with `import whisper` it gives the following ImportError: Numba needs NumPy 1.25 or less.
When I install a specific version of NumPy, in this case version 1.22.4 because of the dependency of SciPy, I still get the same error. When checking what version of Numpy is installed it returns 1.26.1 again. How can I solve the Numpy version installation in Databricks? Other ways or workarounds are also welcome.

I tried installing whisper without dependencies with `!pip install --no-deps -U openai-whisper`.

After that I installed all the individual Whisper dependencies with a specific version:

```
- !pip -q install numpy==1.22.4 
- !pip -q install numba==0.58.0 
- !pip -q install torch==2.1.0 
- !pip -q install triton==2.0.0 
- !pip -q install tiktoken==0.3.3
```

I expected this to resolve the import error, but it returns: Numba needs NumPy 1.25 or less. When checking the numpy version with `numpy.version.version` it says 1.26.1 again.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working. There is a difference between `!pip install` and `%pip install` I didn't know of.

The code `%pip install` restarts the python interpreter after installation. When I checked the numpy version with the code `%pip install`, it returned the correct version 1.22.4.